# How can I browse my windows partition from Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I can boot into my Windows XP or Ubuntu 10.04 with no problem.  When I was on 9.10, I can usually browse to my windows partitions with the File Browser.  Now that I have upgraded to 10.04, I can't see my windows partitions anymore through File Browser.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: First of all you should check if you windows partition is auto-mount when the system boot, it happen when updating that it clear some auto-mount stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the line into the 'fstab'.
Open it with: `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` 
Start a new line with the following content:
`/dev/sdaX  /mnt/WIN  ntfs-3g  0  0`
First one is the partition. Look it up which one you need with `sudo cfdisk` or `sudo fdisk -l`. 
Then use that in the first part (like /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb3, etc).
Second part is the mount point. You can mount it in your home, in /mnt, /media, etc. I usually just create a new folder like `/mnt/WIN` (sudo mkdir /mnt/WIN), and use that. However you can use the /home/user/ntfs for example. Whatever you want. 
Finally save the file (fstab) and do a `sudo mount /mnt/WIN` (where `/mnt/WIN` is the mount point you used).

Answer (score 1):

System->Administration->Disk Utility
Click on the hard drive name under "Storage Devices". 
Highlight the partition you want to mount under "Volumes".
Click "Mount Volume"
Now you will see the partition in the file browser (Nautilus).